# ASP NET Core 3.1 Razor Pages Ajax call returns html instead of result

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, razor-pages

I am calling a get request in the page model of a razor page.

```
public IActionResult OnGetListOfAddress()
    {
       
    }
```

And the ajax call is:

```
 $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
    url: '?handler=ListOfAddress',
    dataType:'text',
    success: function (data) {
        alert("Request Successful " + data);
     },
       failure: function (response) {
                    alert(response.responseText);
                },
    error: function (e) {
        alert("Request Failed:"+JSON.stringify(e));
    }
```

When called, the result returns success with the html page the ajax call is on(in this case it's the razor page itself).
I've tried debugging and setting a breakpoint on the get request andfound out that when the ajax is called, it does not even hit the breakpoint.

Comment: have you even read the returned html to see what it actually is? it may be some error page ... Looks like there is some filter intercepts the request processing so your breakpoint in the action method is not hit. It's hard to say but you can first try understanding what it shows you in the returned html.

Comment: can you share the return statement of `OnGetListOfAddress()` please?

Comment: return Content("test result");

Comment: @king kong, it's returning the html of header that all the pages share

Comment: I kind of figured out what's going on: my url is not calling the handler it should be calling. Instead it's calling the root index file. I still don't know how to call the current page route with a handler.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in my response to @king kong: I kind of figured out what's going on: my url is not calling the handler it should be calling. Instead it's calling the root index file. I still don't know how to call the current page route with a handler. –

My solution(not practical): is to get the window location and add the handler url to it.

```
let loc  = window.location.href;
 $.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
url:loc+'?handler=ListOfAddress',
dataType:'text',
success: function (data) {
    alert("Request Successful " + data);
 },
   failure: function (response) {
                alert(response.responseText);
            },
error: function (e) {
    alert("Request Failed:"+JSON.stringify(e));
}
```